# Is pattern matching (Elixir, Haskell, etc) a limited form of predicate dispatch?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, pattern-matching, elixir, multiple-dispatch

I am quite a fan of functional programming, I do know about pattern matching and multiple dispatch, and that's how I found about predicate dispatch and was wondering ever since whenever or not it has something to do with pattern matching.

I did read this SO thread: [What is Predicate Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671627/what-is-predicate-dispatch) but still couldn't get my answer regarding the relation between pattern matching and predicate dispatch. I believe that pattern matching and predicate dispatch are indeed similar, if not equivalent, but would like to hear a few opinions.

Consider this Elixir code:

```
def function(%{a_flag: True}=struct) do
    # do smth
end

def function(struct) when is_nil(struct.field) do
    # do smth else
end

def function(struct) do
    # default case
end
```

It does look like the function is picked at runtime based on the properties of the input argument(s), which is exactly what predicate dispatch is. The `when` part looks similar to how predicate dispatch is proposed in this article: [http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~todd/research/oopsla04.pdf](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/%7Etodd/research/oopsla04.pdf)

Please share your knowledge/opinion on this matter.

Comment: `def function(%{a_flag = True}=struct)` is even not a valid [tag:elixir] code in the first place.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin sorry, small typo, should have been `def function(%{a_flag:  True}=struct)`

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't heard of "predicate dispatch", but I can share with you some insights on how Elixir handles pattern matching in function clauses.

Pattern matching in Elixir functions works a bit like routing in web applications: functions are tried **in the order listed** until a match can be made, and then that function is executed.  This means that the *most* specific matches should be listed *first*, and the least-specific (or catch-alls) should be listed *last*. In fact, you will see warnings if you are using an appropriate linter/language-server if you have constructed functions in a way that one cannot be reached.

For example, these definitions are problematic:

```
def something(_) do
   # This would always match 
end

def something(%{foo: nil}) do
   # so this can never match; the previous function def is too broad
end
```

We can rewrite your example a bit to use only pattern matching (instead of using pattern matching and guards):

```
def function(%{x: true} = struct) do
    # do something when x == true
end

def function(%{y: nil}) do
    # do something else when x != true AND y == nil
end

def function(struct) do
    # default case
end
```

The compiler literally turns all of this into a series of conditionals, but the function clauses offer a nice expressive syntax.

Comment: Thank you @Everett, even if I wasn't looking for an explanation of how pattern matching works but rather if it's equivalent to the concept of predicate dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding, it seems predicate dispatch happens at function call level, while pattern matching is just syntactic sugar for if/else and object destructuring.

So, even if they seem related, predicate dispatch is different from pattern matching.